# Public TCP server with C# hosted on my computer

Tags: c#, tcp, server, udp

I'm trying to run a game TCP/UDP server on my computer. It's working fine within the local network, but when I'm trying to run the server with my public IP, it just doesn't work. I've tried to disable the firewall in my router, set port forwarding for port 17000 and added a firewall rule to my computer. I've also bound IP to my computer.

I've checked client calls with Wireshark and I found out that the client (Unity game) is sending data to my IP, but it's giving TCP Retransmission error for every TCP packet that it is trying to send.

There is some of the code from server and client.

Server IP is set to 192.168.0.*:17000

And the client is connecting to my IP with port 17000

**SERVER:**

```
public static void Start(byte _maxPlayers)
    {
        MaxPlayers = _maxPlayers;
        Port = 17000;

        Console.WriteLine("Starting server..");
        InitializeServerData();

        tcpListener = new TcpListener(GetLocalIPAddress(), Port);
        tcpListener.Start();
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(TCPConnectCallback), null);

        udpListener = new UdpClient(Port, GetLocalIPAddress().AddressFamily);
        udpListener.BeginReceive(UDPReceiveCallback, null);

        Console.WriteLine($"Server started on {tcpListener.LocalEndpoint}.");
    }
```

**CLIENT:**

```
public void Connect()
    {
        socket = new TcpClient
        {
            ReceiveBufferSize = dataBufferSize,
            SendBufferSize = dataBufferSize
        };

        receiveBuffer = new byte[dataBufferSize];
        socket.BeginConnect(instance.ip, instance.port, ConnectCallback, socket);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
    {
        socket.EndConnect(_result);

        if (!socket.Connected)
            return;

        stream = socket.GetStream();

        receivedData = new Packet();

        stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveCallback, null);
    }
```

Comment: This is likely happening because the listening socket is only bound on the local network interface.          Try   `new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);`

Comment: @Asti It didn't work, and I think I need to set it to static address, because the router is port forwarding it towards that address, right?

Comment: `Any` should work for all network addresses. Have you checked with a third party tool whether it's possible to reach a TCP server from outside?

Comment: Well so I've checked that port, and it's 'filtered'. So I guess it's still closed, but I have no idea why, because the router is supposed to forward that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found out, that I have two-router set up, and because I was forwarding port 17000 just on one router, it didn't work.